# Counter part of Activity.CreatePingActivity() in SDK 4?

Tags: c#, botframework

There used to be Activity.CreatePingActivity() to determine if the user is still connected to the chat.

What options are available to check connectivity? I tried simply sending an Event like this:

```
message.Type = ActivityTypes.Event;
var response = await BotConnectorClient
    .Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(message as Activity);
```

The response for active chats and for closed webchats are the same.

Comment: What is it you're trying to test? because you can use conversationUpdate to check if a user is added or removed from a bot to see if they're still connected.

Comment: Given userA, i want to know if userB is still connected to the bot. userA and userB are not conversing with each other. I have both of their Conversation References stored. One of the practical application is if I have multiple Agents, I need a system to see which ones/if any one is actively online for a customer handoff.